# MS Access VBA DoCmd.OpenForm using where clause not filtering DAO query based recordset

Tags: forms, ms-access, where-clause, dao

I,m trying to get rid of linked tables and use only VBA code to generate recordset. I found that filtering data using where clause in my DoCmd.OpenForm command doesn't work this way. Is that expected behavior? Or maybe it should work and the problem is located somewhere else... Are OpenArgs the only thing that left me to do this?

To clarify my question:

I have two ms access forms:
One (continuous form) with hyperlink and on click code behind like follows

```
Private Sub txtPerson_Click()
    DoCmd.OpenForm "frmPersonnelDetails", , , "PersonId = " & Me.txtPersonID, acFormReadOnly, acDialog
End Sub
```

and second one (frmPersonnelDetails), not connected to any recordsource, with recordset created with:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    strQuery = "SELECT PersonID, Abbreviation, FirstName, LastName FROM SomeTable"
    Set objDaoDb = GetDAODbConn  'function that returns database connection object
    Set objDaoRS = objDaoDb.OpenRecordset(strQuery, dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)
    Set Me.Form.Recordset = objDaoRS
End Sub
```

Now, where clause doesn't work. Second form is opening always on the first record. Is it normal? What is the best way to make it open on specified record?

Comment: Linked tables is one thing, forms another, completely separated. We cannot guess what you are doing.

Comment: I've edit my question to clarify details.

Comment: The Load event happens after the Open event, so you are resetting what may have been set when opening the form.

Comment: I've tried to pud my code in On Open event. No luck.

Comment: Suppose filter criteria needs to be in query used as Recordset.

Comment: Your filter in `DoCmd.OpenForm` doesn't do anything since your form has no record source. You could pass the PersonID in OpenArgs, and apply it to strQuery. But it seems strange to work around inbuilt features of Access.

Comment: Yeah. That's what I was afraid of. Looks like it is not so easy to quit using linked tables....

Comment: Sorry, I've removed my answer, as `acDialog` complicates this issue somewhat. Probably, as Andre said, using OpenArgs is the easiest solution.

Comment: So sad. To quit using linked tables sounded so very promising, but now it looks so clunky...